# JavaScript Sets lost reference but don't change size

Tags: javascript, object, reference, set

I'm storing objects references inside my JavaScript Sets:

```
let set1 = new Set();
let obj  = {};
```

Then if I use the has() method and the size property of the Set objects I get the next results:

```
console.log(set1.size) //it returns 1
console.log(set1.has(obj)) //it returns true
```

But, if I remove the reference of the object using the next code:

```
obj = null;
```

Then strange behaviour happens to me:

```
console.log(set1.size); //it returns 1 because they are Hard Sets.
console.log(set1.has(obj)); //it returns false
```

In the last line, why does it return false if the size is not changed? Then the reference is lost but the size is not changed.

Comment: You don't "remove a reference", you just overwrite the value of the variable. `Set` still holds its reference to the object (why would not it)

Comment: Thanks @zerkms, how can I do to remove the object completely to affect this Set?

Comment: You need to use the set's `delete` function. `set1.delete(obj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the last line, why does it return false if the size is not changed?

It returns `size = 1` because it still holds one value (a reference to that object).

It returns `false` because it does not has a value that is equals to `null`.

> But, if I remove the reference of the object using the next code:

You just overwrite a value of the variable. After that there is still one reference to the object left (inside the Set).

To remove an element from a `Set` you need to use [`Set.prototype.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete) method:

```
set1.delete(obj);
```

Presumably you need to do that while `obj` still holds a reference to the object.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms it solves that. I thought when the `has()` method was used in the Set object on an Object reference it returned us the updated internal query value. Then I think I need to delete the object itself and the reference using the `Set.prototype.delete()` function.

Answer (score 1):

When you override the value of *obj*:

```
obj = null;
```

You are only changing the value of *obj*, not of the *Set* entry, which still holds a reference to the object that was originally assigned to *obj*.

So the current state is:

```
obj: null
set1: [
   {} // the object assigned to obj
]
```

So your line

```
console.log(set1.has(obj));
```

actually tests, if *set1* contains *null*:

```
console.log(set1.has(null));
```

which is of course false (as it only contains the object).

To actually delete the object from the set, you can use:

```
set1.delete(obj);
```

You could also use a weakSet, if the reference in the set in only used as long as the reference to that object still exists somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @nils, but what is the better way to remove the object content and the reference within the Set? Or is a better option to use WeakSets?

Comment: You can simply use *set1.delete(obj);* you could use a weakSet, if the reference in the set in only used as long as the reference in *obj* still exists.